# Creating Teams in a Firestore Leaderboard

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a game app for which I'd like to implement a leaderboard. I have chosen Firestore as my backend and would like users to be placed in groups of 50 users max (on a first-come first-serve basis). I have a collection of users and would like to create a collection of teams. New teams are created when they have grown to more than 50 users.

A team id is assigned to a field in the user collection on creation of a new user.

My question is, how best to track and grow my teams? Should I use so called cloud functions for this?

Comment: This can be accomplished *with* Cloud Functions and *without*. Neither is by definition better than the other. It all depends on your exact use-case, and what you're more comfortable with. For this precise reason, recommending technology is off topic on Stack Overflow. The recommendation is to try one of the alternatives you have in mind, and see if it works out for you. If it does: great. If it doesn't: try the other alternative. :-)

Comment: Thanks Frank. I'll see what I can do. If anyone has any specifics about how to implement this i.e. how to check to see if the limit of 50 has been reached and then "spawning" another team collection, that would be great.

Comment: This should be fairly straight forward; on your client app when you are about to write a user, check to see if there are already 50 in the prior team and if so, spawn a new team and write the user. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Thanks Jay. That's great